# Reporting Server Configuration Manager Running DB script ERROR

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Trying to configure the database and got the error. Please see attached pic. ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB are already created in my Database. Why would I get this error? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKE57.jpg)

Comment: Kindly put the error message here as text rather than image. Also it is difficult to read text in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by Reinstalling the SQL server 2019 developer edition.